# In React Native Expo go camera is not working in Samsung mobile devices

Tags: react-native, camera, samsung-mobile, expo-go

When I was work on the React native with expo go camera the camera is not working in Samsung  mobile devices a part from that all device is working in IOS also

The Complete code was in the App.js of react native [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X99HC.png)